# Can a Babel plugin extend the parser to add new keywords?

Tags: babeljs

As in the title, is it possible for a Babel plugin to extend the parser in order to add new keywords?

I am using `@babel/core` 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, custom syntax is not currently something that we support. It has been deemed too difficult to implement and maintain in long the long run in a way that wouldn't make it hard for us to develop new features.

Comment: If you look at the various Babel plugins, you will see that they do not implement any parsing logic. They simply enable options in the core Babel parser. If you want to implement a new keyword, then you will have to fork Babel.

Answer (score 0):

With plugins no, but You can fork babel parser and add the support for the custom syntax you need and override the parser on babel, check this interesting article [Can a Babel plugin extend the parser to add new keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187695/can-a-babel-plugin-extend-the-parser-to-add-new-keywords)